# Kakfa spring Integration not throws exception when topic name is incorrect or doesn't exists

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I am using Spring integration to send message to Kakfa channel.When server name is incorrect it throw exception that is good and expected behaviors. But when i gave wrong topic name it fails silently and doesn't throw any exception. Here is config i am using

```
                                        kafka-template="kafkaTemplate"
                                        auto-startup="true"
                                        topic="topicName"   -- if i give incorrect topic name here
                                        sync="false" >
        <int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="requestHandlerAdvice"/>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
        </int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

And kafkaTemplate configuration is

```
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="${kafkaCF_hostName}:${kafkaCF_port}" />
                        <entry key="key.serializer" value="serializer"/>
                        <entry key="value.serializer" value="value.serializer}"/>
                        <entry key="security.protocol" value="${security.protocol}"/>
                        <entry key="ssl.truststore.location" value="${ssl.truststore.location}"/>
                        <entry key="ssl.truststore.password" value="${ssl.truststore.password}"/>
                        <entry key="ssl.keystore.location" value="${ssl.keystore.location}"/>
                        <entry key="ssl.keystore.password" value="${ssl.keystore.password}"/>
                        <entry key="ssl.key.password" value="${ssl.key.password}"/>
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

My requirement is to log the success/failure entry in DB. If i test with wrong topic name then if consider as success and pass to  **requestHandlerAdvice** which is further configures with success /failure channel.

Any advise how to handle this scenario in Kafka with spring integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kafka Client works in two phases on the producer side: it makes a connection to Kafka broker and check for metadata. It is done immediately when you call `send()` on `KafkaTemplate`. The rest of the logic in done in async manner and deferred to some buffer and event loop inside `KafkaProducer`.

So, apparently that wrong topic is also resolved later on and if you rally want to catch it with that `requestHandlerAdvice`, you should consider to have it like this then  `sync="true"`. Or have a look into the `sendFailureChannel` of the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler`:

```
/**
 * Set the failure channel. After a send failure, an
 * {@link org.springframework.messaging.support.ErrorMessage} will be sent
 * to this channel with a payload of a {@link KafkaSendFailureException} with the
 * failed message and cause.
 * @param sendFailureChannel the failure channel.
 */
public void setSendFailureChannel(MessageChannel sendFailureChannel) {
```

The `send-failure-channel` for an XML config.

**UPDATE**

The problem is here `auto.create.topics.enable=false`. It is `true` by default. See this article for more info: https://blog.softwaremill.com/7-mistakes-when-using-apache-kafka-44358cd9cd6

Comment: i tried what you suggested still it's not throwing any exception. It is going to success channel.

Comment: @Arten Bilan any suggestions?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks